# Firefox 100% height and auto scrolling div problems

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, height

I'm looking to create a page with a header, footer and three content columns.  The two outside columns should be fixed width and the center column should take up the remaining width.

The header and footer should be percentage width and the three columns in the center should take up the remaining space.  If the three columns don't fit they should auto scroll.

The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BBVZ9/ works great in IE and Chrome, but firefox scrolls the entire page.

I presume the problem is with the display:table-cell but I haven't been able to find a better way to accommodate the independent scrolling columns and filling middle column.

Any thoughts on how to address this?  I'd prefer a css solution but I can accommodate any js ideas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
html,body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}


#header {
    height: 10%;
    background: gray;

}

#footer {
    height: 10%;
    background: gray;
}

#content {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    display: table;
}

#left0 {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

#right0 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;

}
#nav0 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;   
    height: 100%;

}

#left {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;


}
#right {

    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

}

#nav {
    height: 100%;



}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
 <body>

<div id="header">
HEADER
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="nav0">
  <div id="nav">
 Left
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="left0">
  <div id="left">
  Middle
 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right0">
  <div id="right">
  Right
  </div></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
FOOTER
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the js solution

```
function fixHeight(){
        hnum = window.innerHeight *.8;
        h = hnum.toString();
        document.getElementById("left0").style.height=h+"px";
        document.getElementById("nav0").style.height=h+"px";
        document.getElementById("right0").style.height=h+"px";      
}

window.addEventListener('resize', fixHeight);
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not think I got it right, but I think your problem can be solved with:

```
    ::-moz-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    }
    ::-moz-scrollbar-track {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #fff);
    background:#000;
    }
    ::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #fff;
    background:#7A252B;
    }*
```

I have helped...

Comment: Confused as to how this has anything to do with the question.